# Google Maps API v3 Disable Pinch to Zoom on iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, ipad, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to figure out how to disable the default pinch to zoom functionality on the Google Maps API V3 with Javascript. I tried detecting the touchstart events on the document and nested divs but to no avail. Anyone have any ideas how I can disable this functionality?

**Notes**
I have tried iterating through all the DOM elements looking for the `ontouchstart` events on an interval looking for a way to potentially build a hack but I can't seem to locate any at (using my iPad), so I am unsure how they are even doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out a solution, since my project is full screen the following code did the trick.

```
var tblock = function (e) {
    if (e.touches.length > 1) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }

    return false;
}

document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", tblock, true);
```

Comment: Sorry, unrelated but do you have any idea of how to get a plain map without the controls?

Comment: well if using Google you just need to set the options when creating the Google Map object.