# How to disable google map pinch & spread zoom?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gesture, intel-xdk

I tryed everything to disable pinch & spread zoom for google map, I'm using XDK Intel platform.

This codes which I use:

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapp'), {
    zoom: 17,
    streetViewControl: false,
    panControl: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    TiltGestures: false,
    AllGestures: false,
    ZoomGestures: false,
    ScrollGestures: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: true,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    center: bangalore
    });
```

Comment: Maybe try an transparent overlay over the map which disables the interaction with the map

Comment: Have you check this ticket? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059041/disabling-pinch-zoom-on-google-maps-desktop