# How to disable any zooming in js google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have javascript google maps project where i need to disable any zooming.
My settings:

```
streetViewControl: false,
panControl: false,
disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
TiltGestures: false,
AllGestures: false,
ZoomGestures: false,
ScrollGestures: false,
zoomControl: false,
scrollwheel: false,
navigationControl: false,
mapTypeControl: false,
scaleControl: false,
draggable: true,
disableDefaultUI: true,
minZoom: 8,
maxZoom: 8
```

It work for desktop, but pinch zoom gestures on mobile still in active.

I also try this solution: [disable pinch and zoom in google maps using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138510/disable-pinch-and-zoom-in-google-maps-using-javascript) but it not working for me.

How can i prevent any zooming in my project?

Comment: can  you share a js fiddle

Comment: @ArUn you can see my map on this site: http://orangel-meteo.ru/ in case this is not enough i can try also share my map

Comment: You could set a addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', ... then set the zoom back to the desired value.

Comment: @Emmanuel Delay this is interesting idea, thanks, ill try it soon