# How to disable two fingers zoom option in Maps in mobile devices using JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, responsive-design

My Google Maps options are like

```
{
    center: userLatLng,
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    scaleControl: false,
    draggable: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    styles: styles['hide'],
    componentRestrictions: {country: "in"},
}
```

On mobile, this message is displayed:

> Use two fingers to move the map

If I use two fingers, I can move the map and also zoom it.

**How to make that a single finger can move the map, but not zoom the map?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GMaps v3 Disable Pinch to Zoom on iPad Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10729067/gmaps-v3-disable-pinch-to-zoom-on-ipad-safari)

Comment: Its not a duplicate one but anyhow that one is not resolving my problem.

Answer (score 66):

Add `gestureHandling: "greedy"` to your map options.

Here is the documentation about this option: [gestureHandling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction#gesture-handling)

Comment: Thank you this solution is resolved for using single finger touch instead of double finger touch. And to avoid zoom level i used `maxZoom` option.

Comment: I'm using embedded google map. What I do?

Comment: @Mr.ZeroOne check this doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/interaction-cooperative#maps_interaction_cooperative-html instead of using embedded google map

Answer (score 2):

gestureHandling: "greedy" works for me

please check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction#gesture-handling

Comment: Please post detailed answer first and then references for it.